# Making a class templatized on stream handle both std::cout and an std::ofstream

Tags: c++

I want to write a class StreamContainer that is templatized on Stream:

```
#ifndef STREAMCONTAINER_HPP
#define STREAMCONTAINER_HPP
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
    template<typename Stream>
    class StreamContainer
    {
    public:
        StreamContainer(std::ostream& os)
            : m_stream(os) {} 
    private:
        Stream & m_stream;
    };

#endif
```

I would think that the following client code would work:

```
#include "StreamContainer.hpp"
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("c:\\code\\temp.txt");
    StreamContainer<decltype(std::cout)> coutContainer(std::cout); // C2439
    StreamContainer<std::ofstream> fileContainer(ofs); // C2664
}
```

But that doesn't work, at least in Visual C++ 2015. Trying to pass std::cout causes error C2439 (member could not be initialized) and trying to pass a std::ofstream object causes error C2664 (std::basic_ofstream constructor can't convert argument from std::basic_ostream to const char *). I've also tried using a move constructor, but had other issues with that. Any suggestions as to how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is your constructor parameter `std::ostream&` and not `Stream&`?

Comment: Both can be converted to `std::ostream &`; why not just use that? You don't need a template here.

Comment: Excellent question, @interjay. When I make that change, the problem goes away. I guess I was confusing runtime substitution (a reference to an std::ostream can be a reference to an std::ofstream) with template substitution (a Stream can be an std::ofstream), which needs to be done earlier.

Comment: @AlanStokes, that's also an excellent question. Making that change also solves the problem. The reason I was using a template is that I was trying to code an example based on a class (CSVPrinter) in Alex Korban's "C++11/14 Rocks!" where he had a class that was templatized on a Stream class. He never implemented the part of the code pertaining to the stream, so I was trying to do it as an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
StreamContainer(std::ostream& os)
```

should be:

```
StreamContainer(Stream& os)
```

Otherwise, your `ofstream` instantiation is trying to take an `ofstream&` reference (`m_stream`) to an `ostream` (`os`). The other direction is fine, but this is assigning a base class object to a derived reference.

---

Since you can't deduce class template arguments from constructor arguments, this is a good use-case for just introducing a factory function:

```
template <typename Stream>
StreamContainer<Stream> make_container(Stream& s) {
    return StreamContainer<Stream>{s};
}
```

so that you don't have to repeat the arguments or, worse, use `decltype`:

```
auto coutContainer = make_container(std::cout);
auto fileContainer = make_container(ofs);
```

---

Or, really, both can just be `ostream&` if you don't need any of the type-specifics.